# Cannot connect to my aws ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I am facing "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" error. My previous session was abnormally closed. Now I am not able to connect to my instance.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Below is the debug information

```
ssh -i "aws/githubapi.pem" ubuntu@52.26.94.220 -vv

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 52.26.94.220 http://52.26.94.220 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file aws/githubapi.pem type -1
debug1: identity file aws/githubapi.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

More Information:

```
ssh -v ubuntu@54.148.82.122

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.148.82.122 [54.148.82.122] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/moiz/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/moiz/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/moiz/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/moiz/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/moiz/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/moiz/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/moiz/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/moiz/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Did you made any changes in the sshd configurations or deleted anything inside .ssh folder. If it is not accessible, reboot the machine and try again.

Comment: @AmalGJose Yes, I have edited the sshd_config file but now I have reverted it back, rebooted my local and remote machine both. Still it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intranet firewall was blocking me to send ssh request.